# Effective and real user id matching?

Tags: bash, permissions, users

I have the following script:

```
$ ls -al setprog.sh 
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 52 Αυγ   2 10:23 setprog.sh


$ cat setprog.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while [ True ]
do
    echo $(whoami)
done
```

When running it

```
$ ./setprog.sh 
pkaramol
pkaramol
pkaramol
```

Why the process owner indicated by `ps` (real user) **and** and the user by whom the program is executed (effective user?) match? Shouldn't the one of them be `root` given that the script is owned by him?

```
$ ps aux | grep -i setpr
pkaramol 10294 18.0  0.0  12888  3268 pts/0    S+   10:45   0:00 /bin/bash ./setprog.sh
pkaramol 16746  0.0  0.0  14432  1104 pts/1    S+   10:45   0:00 grep --color=auto -i setpr
```

Comment: Why `echo $(whoami)` instead of just `whoami`?  Why test on the _string_ `True` and not `while true`?

Comment: Because if I echo `whoami` instead of `$(whoami)` it will stdout the string `whoami` instead of the result of the command `whoami`; `True` vs `true` does not make much of a difference;

Comment: What I __did__ notice through is that whenever I edit the file, the `setuid` bit is gone;